# How to add sequence number in input text field HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How to add a sequence number in the following input text box of HTML.

Whenever the user clicks on generate table button then in the input box sequence number should be displayed
like 1, 2, 3
any solution

```js
function generate_table() {
  // get the reference for the body
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  // creating all cells
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    var seqnumber = 1;
    var seq = +1;
    // creates a table row
    
    var row2 = document.createElement('tr');

    

    //====== table first row data =======//
    var seq = document.createElement('td');
    var seqText = document.createTextNode('Seq');
    var l = document.createElement('td');
    var seqText1 = document.createElement('input');

   

    //===== seq generator =====//
    seq.appendChild(seqText);
    row2.appendChild(seq);
    l.appendChild(seqText1);
    row2.appendChild(l);

   

    // add the row to the end of the table body
    tblBody.appendChild(row2);
  
  }

  // put the <tbody> in the <table>
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  // appends <table> into <body>
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
  tbl.setAttribute('border', '2');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Generate a table." onclick="generate_table()" />
```

My jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/shreekantbatale2/bdwLuhgs/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used a `counter` variable, that's what you need?

```js
var counter = 0;

function generate_table() {
  counter++;

  // get the reference for the body
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  // creating all cells
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    var seqnumber = 1;
    var seq = +1;
    // creates a table row
    
    var row2 = document.createElement('tr');

    

    //====== table first row data =======//
    var seq = document.createElement('td');
    var seqText = document.createTextNode('Seq');
    var l = document.createElement('td');
    var seqText1 = document.createElement('input');
 seqText1.value = counter;
   

    //===== seq generator =====//
    seq.appendChild(seqText);
    row2.appendChild(seq);
    l.appendChild(seqText1);
    row2.appendChild(l);

   

    // add the row to the end of the table body
    tblBody.appendChild(row2);
  
  }

  // put the <tbody> in the <table>
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  // appends <table> into <body>
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
  tbl.setAttribute('border', '2');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Generate a table." onclick="generate_table()" />
```